# view virtual memory usage visually while debugging

Tags: linux, memory, virtual

This might be a big ask, but are there any tools that let me view the virtual memory usage of my process in Linux? I am talking detailed, probably graphical view of memory, including what is going into the reserved addresses, the BSS/text/etc segments, heap, stack growth, etc, while I am stepping over the program in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I once used pmap to monitor memory consumption. It helped me a lot in discovering the source of a memory leak. It's far from being graphical but you can learn quite a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. For broad views, maybe just keep dumping /proc/pid/maps? I think pmap, mentioned above, shows info from here. But I guess you are talking about specific small allocs/deallocs.